# Creating a simple Q&A Chatbot with Amazon Lex with Predefined questions and answers

Tags: chatbot, amazon-lex, aws-chatbot

I am doing some research on potential options for building a chatbot. I am currently evaluating amazon Lex. The requirements for the bot are quite simple, a user can ask where to find something, the bot will tell them where in a document they will find the answer. All of these questions and answers have already been captured manually so we can easily have an excel sheet with question and answer.

Is there some way to input these pre-defined questions and responses into Lex? From my research I am having a hard time finding any info on something this basic. It won't really require any back and forth between the user and bot, (for ex. User: 'I need to order flowers' Bot: 'What kind of flowers?"  etc.)

I have seen some info on incorporating Kendra, but I don't think the requirement is sophisticated enough to warrant using it

Ideally I would love to just hardcode it and say this is a question, and this is the response that should be given. Maybe this use case does not need something as powerful as Lex?

Answer (score 0):

Lex can solve your problem at a fraction of the cost of Kendra.
Having said that, Kendra would be easier to work with when compared to Lex.

If you're got some Python capabilities I would recommend you take a look at the [ExcelLexBot](https://github.com/wongcyrus/ExcelLexBot) repo on GitHub. It is a Serverless Application that reads input from an Excel spreadsheet to build up a basic Lex bot for you.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I was taking a look at the repo and it still looks like it is more of a conversational flow vs simple Q&A?    Is there any way to have something like  "Q: Where can I find this?    A: "You can find it here ____"

Comment: @Jim - yes, it is intended for making it easier to build conversational flows but it should still be possible to use it for your purpose too. May require a little massaging but the bulk of the heavy-lifting has already been done for you.